# Is MPI_COMM_WORLD not constant?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, communicator

I read [here](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/introduction-to-groups-and-communicators/), that

> While MPI_Comm_split is the most common communicator creation
>   function, there are many others. MPI_Comm_dup is the most basic and
>   creates a duplicate of a communicator. It may seem odd that there
>   would exist a function that only creates a copy, but this is very
>   useful for applications which use libraries to perform specialized
>   functions, such as mathematical libraries. In these kinds of
>   applications, it’s important that user codes and library codes do not
>   interfere with each other. To avoid this, the first thing every
>   application should do is to create a duplicate of MPI_COMM_WORLD,
>   which will avoid the problem of other libraries also using
>   MPI_COMM_WORLD. The libraries themselves should also make duplicates
>   of MPI_COMM_WORLD to avoid the same problem.

Can MPI_COMM_WORLD be changed after the start of the initialisation of MPI? Is MPI_COMM_WORLD not constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rationale for `MPI_Comm_dup(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ...)` is you do not want a message sent by the MPI app (in `MPI_COMM_WORLD`) is received by the library *under the hood*. Conversely, you do not want the MPI app to receive a message sent by the library.

A simple way of avoiding that is to use a dedicated communicator for the library, and duplicating `MPI_COMM_WORLD` is the simplest way to achieve that.

The answer to your question is `MPI_COMM_WORLD` cannot be changed after `MPI_Init()`. And more generally, communicators cannot be changed once created.